# The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit : Ethereum Smart Contract Deployment Failed:

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

I'm learning how Ethereum smartcontracts are developed and deployed using Solidity, Web3.js, and JavaScript.

I've successfully deployed a contract on Ganache. Now when I'm trying to deployed it on Rinkby Test Net using `truffle-hdwallet-provider. It just fails.

Ive successfully created a web3 object using truffle-hdwallet-provider and I successfully get the account list but the deployment to the testnet always fails.

You can check here that my deployment fails: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x2f20b8F61813Df4e114D06123Db555325173F178

Here is my deploy script

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require ('web3');
const {interface, bytecode} = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    'memonics',                         // this is correct 
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/mylink'  // this is correct 
    );

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async() =>{
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account:', accounts[0]); //This excute fine
    try {
    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface)).deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi There!']}).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});
    console.log('Contract deployed to ', result.options.address);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('ERROR'); // Here I get error 
    }
    

    
};
deploy();
```

and here is my Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Inbox{
    string public message;
    
    constructor (string initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }
    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

I tried using Remix and it deployed successfully but when trying with  truffle-hdwallet-provider it gives this error:

> The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.

I tied with different gas values (up-to max possible) but still no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the bytecode not including `0x` caused this problem.

By concatenating **`0x`** with the bytecode, I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `'0x0' +` inside `deploy` just before bytecode.

```
.deploy({ data:'0x0' + bytecode })
.send({ gas: "1000000", gasPrice: "5000000000", from: accounts[0] });
```

Comment: it should be '0x' + bytecode, not '0x0'

Comment: thanks, it worked. In old versions of web3js+soldity, there was only "0x"+bytecode. but now its "0x0"+bytecode

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and solved it by pasting the flattened code into Remix that then gave a better error description: I had an interface in the contract that I had not implemented correctly (wrong function signature). Check your interface implementations. Trying to deploy an "abstract contract" gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

when deploying to sepolia network, i did this and it worked out fine :

```
const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
.deploy({data: '0x' + bytecode, arguments: ['Hello there']})
.send({from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'})
```

just affix '0x' to the bytecode